# Why do I receive this FutureWarning when I use xgboost?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xgboost

I'm using `xgboost` to train a binary classifier with script

```
class_weights = list(class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(y_train),y_train))
w_array = np.ones(len(y_train), dtype='float')
for i, val in enumerate(y_train):
    w_array[i] = class_weights[val]    

eval_set = [(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val)]
model = XGBClassifier(max_depth=5,n_estimators=1000)
model.fit(x_train, 
          y_train,
          verbose=0,
          eval_set=eval_set,
          eval_metric='auc',
          sample_weight=w_array,
          early_stopping_rounds=200)
```

In the above script, `x_train` and `x_val` are arrays of shapes `(386, 72)` and `(387, 72)`, respectively. `y_train` and `y_val` are arrays of zeros and ones. Running the script, I will receive a warning

```
FutureWarning: Pass classes=[0 1], y=[1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] as keyword args. From version 0.25 passing these as positional arguments will result in an error
  FutureWarning)
```

What does this mean?

My `xgboost` version is `0.81` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refers to `compute_class_weight`. It asks you to explicitly pass the classes you try to predict.

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html):

> classes : *ndarray*
>
> Array of the classes occurring in the data, as given by np.unique(y_org) with y_org the original class labels.